# Camera2Video implementing pause resume? But output file contain paused frames

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am trying to implement pause and resume functionality in google [Camera2video](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Video) sample. I am using hardware pipeline in it.

So I have implemented pause and resume functionality inside my App.

- I managed to paused hardware Pipeline. by

  renderHandler.stopRecording()

### But there is a problem

- for example:  I record video for 3 seconds and pause for 3 and then record for 3s. **The output file generated is 9 seconds**. 3seconds video then no frames for 3second and 3 second video.
- on paused state Muxer is not writing data "                            mMuxer.writeSampleData(mVideoTrack, encodedData, mBufferInfo)
  " But it is not possible to start muxer after stopping.
- stoping and starting mediacodes crashes the app
- stoping and starting encoder crashes the app.

How can the output video file not contain the pause state?